# lambda aws python get url id

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently learning aws, lambda, and python all at ones. 
Have been going well till I am trying to get an id from the browser.

```
https://[apinumber].execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod?id=1
```

I have put the right settings (I think) in aws
I have put this setting under resources -> method request -> URL Query String Parameters

[image]

What would be the best way to get this id?

I have tried many ways but didn't really find a solution yet. 
I have been stuck with this for the last days.

```
    #always start with the lambda_handler
    def lambda_handler(event, context):

        # get page id
        page_id = event['id']

if page_id:
        return page_id
    else:
        return 'this page id is empty'
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
Needed to add the mapping terms in integration request -> mapping (below page)

```
{
   "id": "$input.params('id')"
}
```

The function is now working.